# Problema para mostrar u ocultar un JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 3 JFrames para varias cosas, en el primero se ingresan datos que se mandan a los otros 2 JFrames uno para mostrar los datos en una tabla y el otro para mostra los datos en un grafico, al primero le asigno setVisible(true) y al segundo setVisible(false), mi problema esta en que en el JFrame con la tabla tengo un boton con el que pensaba que cambiara el false del grafico por true para mostrarlo, pero siempre da error ¿se debe hacer asi o hay otra forma?

Codigo del primer JFrame

```
        vr = new vent_resultado();
        vr.setVisible(true);
        vr.CargarInterfaz();

        gt = new grafico();

        for(int $i=1;$i<=Cant_Rep;$i++)
        {                
            double ps = Porc_Sobr.generarDU();
            double pf = Porc_Ferm.generarDU();
            double pd = Porc_Desc.generarDN();
            Viñedo = (Kil_Hec * Hec_Util) * (ps * 0.01);
            Descarte = Viñedo * (pd * 0.01);
            Seleccion = Viñedo - Descarte;
            Fermentado = Seleccion * (pf * 0.01) * Tiem_Ferm;    
            Ferm_Espum = Seleccion * (pf * 0.01) * (Tiem_Ferm * 2);
            Maduracion = Fermentado * (Lit * 0.01);
            Mad_Espum = Ferm_Espum * (Lit * 0.01);
            Vinos_Jov = Maduracion;
            Vinos_Añe = Maduracion * (Porc_Cons * 0.01);
            Vinos_Esp = Mad_Espum * (Porc_Cons * 0.01);

            double de = Demanda_Esp.generarDN();
            double dj = Demanda_Jov.generarDT();
            double da = Demanda_Añe.generarDT();
            Ing_Jov = Vinos_Jov * Precio_Jov * dj;
            Ing_Añe = Vinos_Añe * Precio_Añe * da;
            Ing_Esp = Vinos_Esp * Precio_Esp * de;
            Ing_Totales = Ing_Jov + Ing_Añe + Ing_Esp;
            Gastos_Jov = Vinos_Jov * Costo_Jov;
            Gastos_Añe = Vinos_Añe * Costo_Añe;
            Gastos_Esp = Vinos_Esp * Costo_Esp;
            Gastos_Tot = Gastos_Jov + Gastos_Añe + Gastos_Esp + Costo_Fijo;
            Ganan_Jov = Ing_Jov - Gastos_Jov;
            Ganan_Añe = Ing_Añe - Gastos_Añe;
            Ganan_Esp = Ing_Esp - Gastos_Esp;
            Ganan_Tot = Ing_Totales - Gastos_Tot;

            vr.mostrarDatos(Viñedo,Descarte,Seleccion,Fermentado,Ferm_Espum,Maduracion,Mad_Espum,Vinos_Jov,Vinos_Añe,Vinos_Esp,Ing_Jov,Ing_Añe,Ing_Esp,Ing_Totales,Gastos_Jov,Gastos_Añe,Gastos_Esp,Gastos_Tot,Ganan_Jov,Ganan_Añe,Ganan_Esp,Ganan_Tot,$i);
            gt.graficar(Vinos_Jov,Vinos_Añe,Vinos_Esp,$i);
        }
        gt.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
```

Codigo del boton del JFrame con la tabla

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    gt.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: No deberías de usar caracteres fuera del rango ASCII para nombrar tus variables

Comment: ¿a cuales caracteres te refieres?

Comment: A los que no son parte del conjunto ASCII

Comment: Cuando dices: "siempre da error", exactamente, ¿a qué tipo de error te refieres?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @user85131 te recomiendo leer la respuesta de esta pregunta: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42978/66587)  Al parecer te hace falta crear la instancia de tu objeto antes de utilizar sus métodos.